# Intel HD Graphics 3000 (i5-2540M) support for 2K 27"

Tags: graphics-card, display, resolution

I have nowadays quite old laptop T420 with i5-2540M with integrated graphics Intel HD Graphics 3000. I wonder if this will be sufficient for connecting some sort of low-end monitor suitable for photo editing. Something like 27" IPS up to 2K resolution.
I wasn't able to find out any information on intel specs site. I have a DP so it could be possible but I don't know if there is a support for such resolution and also even when there will be support, if my laptop won't burn a hole into my desk when I start work with it :D

**EDIT:** Resolution of monitors I'm currently looking for is 2560x1440 (QHD?)

Comment: What resolution do you mean by 2K? Exactly in pixels, please.

Comment: @gronostaj my fault, I am confused of the resolutions little bit. Most of the monitors I have seen has QHD? 2560x1440.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum resolution of the Intel HD Graphics 3000 as indicated in many sources is
2500x1600
([example](https://www.game-debate.com/hardware/index.php?gid=581&graphics=Intel%20HD%20Graphics%203000%20Mobile)),
although you might need the DisplayPort to achieve it.
The real maximum also depends on your monitor.

This maximal resolution is also possible for HDMI although you may need to lower the
refresh rate, which is only a problem when gaming.

A test case is found in the article
[How to run a WQHD monitor at 2,560 x 1,440 via HDMI on an Intel HD3000, HD4000](https://www.itproportal.com/2013/06/04/how-to-run-a-wqhd-monitor-at-2560-x-1440-via-hdmi-on-an-intel-hd3000-hd4000/).

Comment: as I wrote in my question I have DisplayPort, so there shouldn't be a problem. I just didn't know if my integrated graphics on i5-2540M will handle such resolution for work with photos but sometimes maybe for movies.

Comment: With the DisplayPort you are not supposed to have any problem, as far as specifications go.

Comment: Ok so you think also performance will be fine? Not going to play games on it. But maybe a movie could be a problem or not?

Comment: I think you will be fine, but of course cannot give a guarantee.

Comment: Understand.. I think I'm going to try it :) After that I will post a result.

Comment: @Gondil So, what is the result?

Comment: @Exterminator13 hello sorry, forget to post an update. My 27" WQHD monitor is working just fine with Intel HD Graphics 3000 (i5-2540M). Using a DP. Havent tried with HDMI yet.

Comment: @Gondil Thanks for response! What is the resolution and refresh rate?

Comment: @Exterminator13 resolution is 2560x1440 and refresh rate is set to 59Hz

Comment: @Gondil Hmmm... that's strange... As I understood from the sources, the max allowed refresh rate cannot be more than 40 Hz, e.g. 2560x1440@40. It is caused by max video data throughput, which the integrated video accelerator can provide. (That's why, it doesn't matter whether it is HDMI or DP)